# Using variable that depends on response text

Tags: jmeter

In my test plan I create a new object in my website, which gets some ID, which is returned in response code. I need to use this ID to select objects later in my test plan when sending requests. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a regular expression extractor to scrape the ID from the response.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor